# Office 365 Unified API Mail Enabled Groups

Tags: office365, office365api

Earlier today I was able to create mail enabled groups via the Unified API. I now get the following error:

> "The service does not currently support writes of mail-enabled groups. Please ensure that the mail-enablement property is unset and the security-enablement property is set."

The API now only allows the mail enabled flag to be set to false. There has been no updates to the documentation on Microsofts website, it continues to say that this is possible.

Is anybody else experiencing this, can anyone from Microsoft say if this is a deliberate change.

Answer (score 1):

You must use this your passed JSON:

```
"groupTypes":["Unified"],
"mailEnabled":"true",
```

If you don't specify ["Unified"] and just leave it blank [], you can't set an email address because the group is not a distribution group.  If you try to specify anything else (i.e. ["Distribution"]), you'll receive an error.

Either the documentation is not clear, or there are still bugs in the API.

I also used:

```
"securityEnabled":"false"
```

I also issue a PATCH after the group is created in order to have any added users receive all emails to their inbox:

```
AutoSubscribeNewMembers":"true"
```

Answer (score -1):

There has been a breaking change to schema of beta version that is responsible for this error. Please refer to http://dev.office.com/blogs/Update-On-Office-365-Unified-API for details.